# Wagtail: How to pass model instance to a widget and access it in template

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a model based on Wagtails `Page` model and I am assigning a custom widget to one of the models fields. Is it possible to make the model instance accessible in the widgets HTML-template when rendering the admin view? I need the widget in the admin view to know which ID the `SimplePage` has the widget belongs to, i.e. get the value of `{{ page.id }}`.

```
# models.py
class SimplePage(Page):

    name = RichTextField(blank=True)
    geom = PointField()

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("geom", widget=LeafletWidgetWithMedia()),
    ]
```

```
# widgets.py
class LeafletWidgetWithMedia(LeafletWidget):
    include_media = True
    template_name = "admin/widget.html"
```

I know I can update the context of my widget like so:

```
# widgets.py
# ...
    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        value = None if value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES else value
        context = super(LeafletWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context.update(self._get_attrs(name, attrs))
        return context
```

But I can't figure how to get my `SimplePage` instance into the widget to update the context. (I also tried Wagtails `before_edit_page` [hook](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#editor-workflow) w/o success.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is available to the edit handler, not the widget. You could use a custom edit handler which re-initialises the widget once it knows what the page instance is. Something like this:

```
class LeafletPanel(FieldPanel):

    def on_instance_bound(self):
        self.widget = LeafletWidgetWithMedia(page_instance=self.instance)
```

`on_instance_bound()` is called when the panel is bound to a page object. Note that when creating a new page, this will not get called - so you may need some logic in the widget to handle that case.

You then adjust your `LeafletWidgetWithMedia` to accept this `instance` argument at initalisation, and can pass that into the context from the `get_context()` method:

```
class LeafletWidgetWithMedia(LeafletWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.instance = kwargs.pop('page_instance', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        # ...
        context['page_instance'] = self.instance
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time to explain this. It worked like a charm.

Comment: Nice one! I think hat:
context['page_instance'] = self.page_instance

should be: 
context['page_instance'] = self.instance right?

Comment: Quite right @maerteijn, I've corrected it.