# Wagtail: Pass a vanilla Django model instance to widget

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a model based on Django's **`models.Model`** which I register via `ModelAdmin` in the admin view. One of my fields has a custom widget assigned to it.

```
# models.py
panels = [
    # ...
    CustomFieldPanel('geom', widget=LeafletWidgetWithMedia)
    # ...
    ]
```

I need the widgets context to be aware of the model instance. Here is what I tried so far, based on an answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894242/wagtail-how-to-pass-model-instance-to-a-widget-and-access-it-in-template) I posted before. I updated the `FieldPanel` to pass the instance to the widget.

```
class CustomFieldPanel(FieldPanel):
    def on_instance_bound(self):
        self.widget = LeafletWidgetWithMedia(page_instance=self.instance)
```

Then I updated the `__init__` and the `get_context` functions of the Widget:

```
class LeafletWidgetWithMedia(LeafletWidget):
    include_media = True
    template_name = "admin/widget.html"

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        print("Kwargs: " + str(kwargs))
        self.page_instance = kwargs.pop("page_instance", None)
        print("Instance: " + str(type(self.page_instance)))
        # ...

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        value = None if value in validators.EMPTY_VALUES else value
        context = super(LeafletWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context["page_instance"] = self.page_instance
        context.update(self._get_attrs(name, attrs))
        print("Page instance in context: " + str(self.page_instance))
        return context
```

This approach works flawless if my model is based on Wagtails `Page` model but here the context won't get updated. The print statements in the `__init__` show the instance gets passed to the widget:

```
# Kwargs: {'page_instance': <MyModel: 7>}
# Instance: <class 'register.models.MyModel'>
```

But the instance seems to never reach `get_context`. The print statement in `get_context` shows:

```
# Page instance in context: None
```

Inspecting the rendered templates context shows that the key got set but the value is `none`.

```
# admin/widget.html
# ...
 'name': 'geom',
 'page_instance': None,
 'required': True,
# ...
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Do your console logs show the widget being initialised more than once? I suspect that's what's happening - i.e., something is reinitialising the widget before it gets rendered. Don't know why that would be though.

Comment: It seems so. I can see in the console one "empty" initialization, i.e. `kwargs: {}` and `Instance: None` then three initialization with my instance properly passed over. And then `Page instance in context: None` gets printed. I tried to follow the whole flow with `ipdb.set_trace()` but, well, there is a lot going on I do not fully understand.

Comment: Sorry for dragging you in again BTW. It worked like a charm with the `Page` model ,thanks to you, but unfortunately I have to use Django's vanilla model.

Comment: It seems like the widget is being [passed to the form here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/40dbb940e7fb67b83cda1ed7dfab1644133bb8f9/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py#L355), which happens before it has been attached to an instance. I can't see a straightforward way to achieve what you want - hopefully someone else will be able to help.

Comment: I also stumbled upon `widget_overrides` but wasn't sure about it's importance. Do you think this use case might justify opening a Git issue?

Comment: You could try, but I suspect your use case is not very common. Widgets are supposed to be agnostic of the wider context that they are used in - it's quite unusual to want to pass context like yours that far down. I think you might be better of just writing a custom view that does what you want.

Comment: I hear you ;-) I think I am going to post a new question being more specific about what I want. Maybe the approach of passing down the instance that far isn't even necessary. Thank you again.